# Utilizing Knockout Updating Viewmodel Based on Select Checkbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I've been working on an ASP.NET MVC4 web application, and I'm trying to keep some persistent data of selected/deselected items on the user side.

Essentially, I have an HTML table which I've converted into a Kendo Grid. The table/grid has been populated by accessing Oracle and SQL servers on the back end and strongly typing a model to the view in order to create and populate the table via that model. I'm trying to update a an ObservableArray found in my ViewModel based on whether the select checkbox has been checked or not, but I've been spinning circles for quite a while. Below is a basic framework of what I have implemented. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML Table:

```
    <table id="grid" border="1">
     <thead id="tableHead">
            <tr align="center">
                <th data-field="select" id="selectChkBox"> Select</th>
                <th data-field="model">Model</th>
                <th data-field="division">Division</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tableBody" class="hoverTable">
            @foreach (var config in Model.Models)
            {
                <tr align="right" id="entries">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkBox" data-bind="checked: addModel" id="checkbox" value="@config.ModelName"/></td>
                    <td>@config.ModelName</td>
                    <td>@config.Division</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

JavaScript/Knockout ViewModel:

```
function PRPSSelectViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.AvailableModels = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.ModelNames = ko.observableArray([]);

    // Operations
    self.addModel = function (name) {
        self.ModelNames.push(name);
    };

    self.removeModel = function (name) {
        self.ModelNames.remove(name);
    };
}
```

I'm sure that many variations of this problem have been documented, however I'm very new to Knockout and have been unable to implement my desired functionality despite the outpouring of resources and examples made available.

**EDIT**
Solved using a simple method. I just instantiated an array in my Javascript file which I'm using to populate with the names of the models. I already had some Javascript setup to to trigger when a checkbox was marked to 'select' it on the kendo grid, and by just grabbing the appropriate row, I'm able to populate the array with the model name. As long as the page doesn't refresh (and it shouldn't since I'm utilizing modals and partial views for by CRUD operations), I should be okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html):

> For checkboxes, KO will set the element to be checked when the parameter value is true, and unchecked when it is false. **If you give a value that isn’t actually boolean**, it will be interpreted loosely. This means that nonzero numbers and non-null objects and non-empty strings will all be interpreted as true, whereas zero, null, undefined, and empty strings will be interpreted as false.

I've highlighted the issue you have - you're using function instead of observable. In your view model add property:

```
self.isChecked = ko.observable(false);
self.isChecked.subscribe(function(newValue) {
   if (newValue == true) 
       self.addModel(<observable with model name>);
   else
       self.removeModel(<observable with model name>);
});
```

You should save current ModelName somewhere in your view model.

And in your markup make this change:

```
....
<td><input type="checkbox" class="chkBox" data-bind="checked: isChecked" id="checkbox" value="@config.ModelName"/></td>
....
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I ended up speaking with one of my project managers, and apparently for my purposes, utilizing Knockout is somewhat irrelevant since I'm not using a ViewModel of the MVVM architecture of Knockout to populate my table. The simplification of keeping track and binding objects/information is lost based on how I populate my table, so I have to approach it in a different manner.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, knockout is a great framework. You could populate your arrays on initialization stage of your view model, it's a common practise. Good luck anyway.

Comment: Looks like it. If only I'd known of it before I started developing this web app. And thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved similar behavior recently, my working code is quite similar to following code js view model only. Refer this fiddle for full working example. http://jsfiddle.net/sbirthare/KR4a6/19/

See if this helps.

> var initialData = [
>       {
>           availableItems: [
>             { title: "US", isSelected: true },
>             { title: "Canada", isSelected: false },
>             { title: "India", isSelected: false }]
>       },
>       {
>           selectedItems: [
>             { "title": "US" },
>             { "title": "Canada" }
>           ]
>       }
>   ];
>
> function Item(titleText, isSelected) {
>       this.title = ko.observable(titleText);
>       this.isSelected = ko.observable(isSelected);
>   }
>
> var SelectableItemViewModel = function (items) {
>       // Data
>       var self = this;
>       self.filter = ko.observable("");
>       self.availableItems = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(items[0].availableItems, function (item) {
>           return new Item(item.title, item.isSelected);
>       }));

```
self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(items[1].selectedItems, function (item) {
    return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.availableItems(), function (itm){
        return item.title == itm.title();
    });

}));

    //filter the items using the filter text
self.filteredItems = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    debugger;
    var filter = this.filter().toLowerCase();
    if (!filter) {
        return this.availableItems();
    } else {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.availableItems(), function (item) {
            return ko.utils.stringStartsWith(item.title().toLowerCase(), filter);
        });
    }
}, self);

// Operations

self.removeItem = function (removedItem) {
    self.selectedItems.remove(removedItem);
};}
```

> var vm = new SelectableItemViewModel(initialData);
>
> $(document).ready(function () {
>       ko.applyBindings(vm);
>   });